# Check whether values in one data frame column exist in a second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames (A and B), both with a column 'C'. I want to check if values in column 'C' in data frame A exists in data frame B.

```
A = data.frame(C = c(1,2,3,4))
B = data.frame(C = c(1,3,4,7))
```

Comment: `setdiff` may be of interest

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use `%in%` as follows

```
A$C %in% B$C
```

Which will tell you which values of column C of A are in B.

What is returned is a logical vector.  In the specific case of your example, you get:

```
A$C %in% B$C
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Which you can use as an index to the rows of `A` or as an index to `A$C` to get the actual values:

```
# as a row index
A[A$C %in% B$C,  ]  # note the comma to indicate we are indexing rows

# as an index to A$C
A$C[A$C %in% B$C]
[1] 1 3 4  # returns all values of A$C that are in B$C
```

We can negate it too:

```
A$C[!A$C %in% B$C]
[1] 2   # returns all values of A$C that are NOT in B$C
```

---

If you want to know if a specific value is in B$C, use the same function:

```
  2 %in% B$C   # "is the value 2 in B$C ?"  
  # FALSE

  A$C[2] %in% B$C  # "is the 2nd element of A$C in B$C ?"  
  # FALSE
```

Comment: The last expression would tell you whether the second value in A$C were in B$C.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  In the original example `A$C[2]` is `2`, hence the lack of clarity.  I edited the comments in my example to hopefully clarify.

Comment: This is really useful; how might we extend this technique to search for a string within a given variable?  Can we combine with `str_detect` ?