# find unique factors in one variable that don't exist in another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two variables in R in the same data frame with lists of factors, each with some duplication like this:

```
v1 <- c("a1","a1","b2","b2","d4","c3","d4")
v2 <- c("a1","c3","d4","d4","e5","f6","g7")
A = data.frame(v1, v2)
```

The goal is to return each value in v1 that does not exist in v2, but only once for each unique value. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774773/check-whether-value-exist-in-one-data-frame-or-not'), I have tried the code below which returns "b2 b2":

```
A$v1[!A$v1 %in% A$v2]
```

The actual data I wish to use has over 50,000 cases and each value in v1 appears up to 100 times. Using the same %in% function as above truncates after returning 100 results, but all are the same value because of the duplication in v1.

In sum, how can I query the data frame above and return only the value "b2" once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try `setdiff()`

```
with(A, setdiff(v1, v2))
# [1] "b2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Just wrap it in `unique()`:

```
unique(A$v1[!A$v1 %in% A$v2])
```

or without combining the vectors in a dataframe:

```
unique(v1[!v1 %in% v2])
```

If you want to save the results in a new variable:

```
uni <- unique(A$v1[!A$v1 %in% A$v2])
```

If you want to drop the levels:

```
uni <- droplevels(unique(A$v1[!A$v1 %in% A$v2]))
```

Comment: These both work well, but @richard-scriven 's answer can save the results easily as a new variable: 
`unique <- with(A, setdiff(v1, v2))`

Comment: @ndporter you can do that with this solution as well.

Comment: @ndporter by the way: you should never give your variable the same name as a function

Comment: the last one did work just fine. Thanks. And yeah, I was careless making that variable name. It's been corrected in the real code.