# Check if string equals dataframe element

Tags: r

I have what I thought was a simple task: check if a dataframe element equals a specific value.

I have data on cereal, with columns like Brand, Manufacturer, Calories, etc.

Here's an example row:

```
> data[1, ]
       Brand Manufacturer Calories Protein Fat Sodium Fiber Carbohydrates Sugar Potassium
1 ACCheerios            G      110       2   2    180   1.5          10.5    10        70
```

I thought this would work:

```r
> 'G' == data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] FALSE
```

or maybe

```r
> 'G' %in% data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] FALSE
```

but neither do.

I've checked these previous questions:
[Check if value is in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233798/check-if-value-is-in-data-frame)
[Check whether value exist in one data frame or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774773/check-whether-value-exist-in-one-data-frame-or-not)

Neither seems to do what I want. The only solution I've found so far is to use `unlist()` on the row first, which causes the Brand / Manufacturer to become numbers

```r
> unlist(data[1, ])
        Brand  Manufacturer      Calories       Protein           Fat        Sodium         Fiber Carbohydrates         Sugar 
          1.0           1.0         110.0           2.0           2.0         180.0           1.5          10.5          10.0 
    Potassium 
         70.0
```

and then both solutions above work fine, as long as I use `1` instead of `G`.

```r
> 1 == unlist(data[1, ])[2]
Manufacturer 
        TRUE 

> 1 %in% unlist(data[1, ])[2]
[1] TRUE
```

My thought is that this isn't working because when I simply print out `data[1, ]$Manufacturer`, more than just the column is returned. Something about "Levels" is returned too:

```r
> data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1]  G
Levels:  G  K  Q
```

I've tried doing `data[1, ]$Manufacturer[1]` (and various other things to try and just return the `G`) to no avail.

How do I do this relatively simply task?

Comment: Why not just do `which(df=="G")`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

The most important thing here is the following:

> My thought is that this isn't working because when I simply print out data[1, ]$Manufacturer, more than just the column is returned. Something about "Levels" is returned too:

If it returns with the "Levels", then it means your variable is a **factor**. I really recommend you visit [this page](https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html) or [this page](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/13-supp-data-structures/) to learn about basic data types in R.

Create a data frame

```r
df = data.frame(A = c("Aa", "Bb","Cc", "Dd"),B=c(1,2,3,4), C=c(5,6,7,8))
str(df) 
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ A: Factor w/ 4 levels "Aa","Bb","Cc",..: 1 2 3 4
#>  $ B: num  1 2 3 4
#>  $ C: num  5 6 7 8
```

Following the [example SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233798/check-if-value-is-in-data-frame) you said you tried:

```r
"Aa" %in% df
#> [1] FALSE
any(df=="Aa") 
#> [1] TRUE
Reduce("|", df=="Aa") 
#> [1] TRUE
length(which(df=="Aa"))>0 
#> [1] TRUE
is.element("Aa",unlist(df[1,])) 
#> [1] FALSE
```

Moving to your original attempts:

```r
## Search when column 1 ("A") is a *factor*
"Aa" %in% df[1,] # Checking the entire row for a CHARACTER elemtn "Aa"
#> [1] FALSE
"Aa" %in% df[1,1] # Checking the first row and first column for character element "Aa"
#> [1] TRUE
"Aa" %in% df$A # Index a speific column
#> [1] TRUE
factor("Aa") %in% df$A # Also works if we specify the search criterion as a factor
#> [1] TRUE
```

Search when column 1 ("A") is a *factor*:

```r
# Force df$A to a character 
df$A <- as.character(df$A)
str(df) #now we have a character, numeric, and numeric
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ A: chr  "Aa" "Bb" "Cc" "Dd"
#>  $ B: num  1 2 3 4
#>  $ C: num  5 6 7 8
```

You were originally trying to scan the entire row:

```r
"Aa" %in% df[1,] 
#> [1] TRUE
```

Try the other options again, just to check the behavior:

```r
"Aa" %in% df[1,1] # Checking the first row and first column for character element "Aa"
#> [1] TRUE
"Aa" %in% df$A # Index a speific column
#> [1] TRUE
factor("Aa") %in% df$A # Also works if we specify the search criterion as a factor
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The style of operations you need is realized if you change data.frame into data.table:

```
data <- as.data.table(data)
'G' == data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] TRUE
'G' %in% data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] TRUE
```

or changing factors into characters:

```
data$Manufacturer <- as.character(data$Manufacturer)
 'G' == data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] TRUE
'G' %in% data[1, ]$Manufacturer
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Why should that be?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
df[which(df=="G")]
  Manufacturer
1            G
```

Or go for good old `apply`:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) "G"%in%x)
        Brand  Manufacturer      Calories       Protein           Fat        Sodium         Fiber Carbohydrates 
        FALSE          TRUE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE         FALSE 
        Sugar     Potassium 
    FALSE         FALSE
```